# Fetch Google plus friends who are following/like same page

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, google-plus

I need to fetch the friends who are following the same page(profile) but I unable to get those friends.
I have research thoroughly on google plus document but did not find any document related to my requirement. So any of you have faced the same issue before then please lead me in right direction.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.